# Cannot instantiate Tensorflow Interpreter with TFLite model in Java

Tags: java, android, tensorflow

I'm making an Android application using a Tensorflow model I converted to TFLite as follow:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import lite
converter = lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file("myModel.h5")
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("myModel.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

This operation worked and I can instantiate tensorflow.contrib.lite.Interpreter passing the path to *myModel.tflite* in Python.
However, when I try to make an Interpreter in Java, i get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Contents of /file:/android_asset/myModel.tflite does not encode a valid TensorFlowLite model: Could not open '/file:/android_asset/myModel.tflite'.The model is not a valid Flatbuffer file
```

Here is my code:

```
File file = new File("file:///android_asset/myModel.tflite")
c.tfLite = new Interpreter(file);
```

Comment: Are you using Windows or MacOS

Comment: I'm using MacOS 10.11

Comment: This may be an issue with the way we reference File paths when loading File objects. In general, you cannot fopen an asset file path, which may explain the inability to load the model internally. In the meantime, you can either use the [MappedByteBuffer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/java/demo/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tflitecamerademo/ImageClassifier.java#L216) class (if your model is uncompressed), or load it into a regular ByteBuffer. Please file a bug on [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) with the tensorflow lite tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass a file directly, rather use a filechannel

```
private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile() throws IOException {
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = getAssets().openFd("myModel.tflite");
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
        FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
        long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
        long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);

filemap = loadModelFile()
Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(filemap)
```